# How to take QByteArray from std::optional<QByteArray> and leave std::nullopt without additional mallocs?

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I need to write a function that takes ownership of an `optional<QByteArray>`'s underlying array.

In Rust, it is done by this way:

```rust
fn my_func(f: &mut Option<Box<[u8]>>) -> Box<[u8]> {
     //how to do "take" in c++17?
     f.take().unwrap()
}
```

I know about `std::move`, but as far as I understand, this code will `malloc` data for a new array, swap pointers, and drop unneeded `QByteArray`:

```cpp
std::optional<QByteArray> optarr = ...
QByteArray optarr = std::move(*myopt);
optarr.reset()
```

Is there any way to do this as well as in Rust (that is, without allocating memory for temporary `QByteArray`)?

Comment: Can you describe in words the problem you are trying to solve (not as it relates to Rust, but in terms of what you want to accomplish in C++ using plain English)?

Comment: I need to move QByteArray from optional to my variable. Malloc should not be called.

Comment: @chabapok, please be aware that `QByteArray` has its own notion of being ["null"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#isNull) which is different from just being ["empty"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#isEmpty), so wrapping a `QByteArray` inside a `std::optional` is pointless in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent<sup>†</sup> function in C++ would be:

```
auto func(optional<QByteArray>&& o) -> QByteArray
{
    return std::move(o).value();
}
```

`std::move(o)` gives you an rvalue of type `optional<QByteArray>`. Invoking `value()` on that rvalue gives you a `QByteArray&&` (or throws if `o` is disengaged). That rvalue of type `QByteArray` is used to move construct the return object. This move construction is cheap, just a few pointer assignments - no memory allocation happens.

---

<sup>†</sup>Almost equivalent. Note that `o` here does *not* end up as a disengaged `optional`, unlike in Rust. It is still engaged, just holding an empty `QByteArray`. Truly equivalent, if really desired, would be:

```
auto func(optional<QByteArray>&& o) -> QByteArray
{
    QByteArray result = std::move(o).value(); // NB: not a reference
    o.reset();                                // or '= nullopt', or '= {}'
    return result;                            // NB: no need to move
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that the trailing return type syntax was possible in C++ :o

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption about [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is wrong. Roughly speaking std::move casts to an rvalue reference, no actual code is generated in itself by that. The following line will create a `QByteArray` on the stack by calling its move constructor.

```
QByteArray optarr = std::move(*myopt);
```

The move constructor initializes the `Data` pointer from the other QByteArray and replaces the other's data pointer with pointer to shared empty data. No `malloc` is involved, just two pointer assignments.

The [implementation](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.h.html) of the move constructor looks like this:

```
inline QByteArray(QByteArray && other) Q_DECL_NOTHROW : d(other.d) { other.d = Data::sharedNull(); }
```

So your code is actually doing what you want.